# Vugen Ajax TruClient Database Connection

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle, database-connection, loadrunner

So I have been playing with Ajax TruClient bu I have not figured out what functions(if any) allow me to connect to a database(oracle) to pull information and compare against the UI. Anyone knows?

Also I have tried the Web and Click and script protocols which allow DB Connections but my page relies heavily in JS and Ajax so those are not much of an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the database functions that are available within LoadRunner. The "Function Reference" (F1 help/search) says that they are only available for the Web Services protocol, but they work just fine with TruClient. You need to create your own functions in the C-functions.c file and use the available LoadRunner functions. Then from TruClient, you can "evaluate c" and call the function you created.

The available database functions are:

1. lr_db_connect()
2. lr_db_disconnect()
3. lr_db_executeSQLStatement()
4. lr_db_dataset_action()
5. lr_db_getvalue()

You can search for these in the function reference guide and they actually show you examples with what parameters are required, etc.

So for example, in my C-functions.c file, I have created a function:

```
void connect_db(){
    lr_db_connect("StepName=myStepName", "ConnectionString=myConnString", "ConnectionName=myConnName", "ConnectionType=ORACLE", LAST);
}
```

I can then use the "evaluate C" option from the toolbox within TruClient and call my connect_db function.

Answer (score 0):

"pull information and compare against the UI."

You are thinking functionally and you will likely double your load to the database.    This is bad magic for performance testing to include these extra queries not found in production in your test for 100% of the time you will create an extra bottleneck in the system.

Decouple your functional and performance testing.   Answer the question of "does it work for one" before answering the question of "does it work for many?"